# Allowing an email as the username?

Tags: users, user-access, user-meta, username

Is it possible to allow people to utilize their email as their username?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as i know it should be possible to login with your email with wp 3.1, which will come soon.

Using an email as username is already possible. "@" and "." are allowed characters for usernames. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using WP 3.2.1 and still cannot log in with the email address. Do I need a special setting? Or should the username be the same like the email address?

Comment: Seems so. That was at least what I read on a ticket, [but currently I can't find it.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/search?q=login+mail&noquickjump=1&ticket=on&milestone=on&changeset=on&wiki=on)

Answer (score 3):

This plugin says it is possible http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email-login/
It Lets you use your email address to log into your WordPress account instead of a username.